# XSLT current() is not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have created the following XML

```
<Shipment>
  <ShipmentHeader>
    <Welcome>HI</Welcome>
  </ShipmentHeader>             
  <ShipmentStop>
    <StopSequence>STOP1</StopSequence>
    <ShipmentStopDetail>
      <Try>OTP</Try>
    </ShipmentStopDetail>
    <ShipmentStopDetail>
      <Try>OTP</Try>
    </ShipmentStopDetail>
  </ShipmentStop>
  <ShipmentStop >
    <StopSequence>STOP2</StopSequence>
    <ShipmentStopDetail>
      <Try>OTP</Try>
    </ShipmentStopDetail>
    <ShipmentStopDetail>
      <Try>OTP</Try>
    </ShipmentStopDetail>
  </ShipmentStop>
</Shipment>
```

This is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    xmlns:pfx4='http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm'>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <ZPOINT>
        <xsl:for-each select="Shipment">
          <xsl:for-each select="ShipmentStop">
            <xsl:for-each select="ShipmentStopDetail">
              <LSQNUM>                     
                <xsl:value-of select="Shipment/ShipmentStop[current()]/StopSequence[current()]"/>
              </LSQNUM>
              <Change>                     
                <xsl:value-of select="Shipment/ShipmentStop[current()]/StopSequence[current()]/ShipmentStopDetail[current()]"/>
              </Change>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ZPOINT>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to perform a substring operation, but the output is not as I expected. The XPath-expression returns `null`. Can someone help me? Where am I going wrong?

Below is my output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZPOINT xmlns:pfx4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
   <LSQNUM/>
   <LSQNUM/>
   <LSQNUM/>
   <LSQNUM/>
</ZPOINT>
```

And the expected result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZPOINT xmlns:pfx4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
    <LSQNUM>STOP1</LSQNUM>
    <Change>OTP<Change>
    <LSQNUM>STOP1</LSQNUM>
    <Change>OTP<Change>
    <LSQNUM>STOP2</LSQNUM>
    <Change>OTP<Change>
    <LSQNUM>STOP2</LSQNUM>
    <Change>OTP<Change>
</ZPOINT>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  `current()` returns the current context node, which at that point would be the ShipmentStopDetail node being processed..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What is the expected result, and why?

Comment: @Matthew Actually the context node is `ShipmentStopDetail` - but since the expression is in brackets it refers to the location step as its context node.

Comment: Hi guys I have added my expected result,Why xpath is returning null value?

Comment: @SatheeshKumar Please explain the **logic** by which the result is achieved. It would be also best to edit your example so that the strings do not repeat themselves so.

Comment: My logic is for every ShipmentStopDetail  I need to map <LSQNUM> and the value must be picked from the current ShipmentStop/StopSequence but its returning null,I have made my example more simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My logic is for every ShipmentStopDetail I need to map `<LSQNUM>` and
>   the value must be picked from the current ShipmentStop/StopSequence

That could be achieved very simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Shipment">
    <ZPOINT xmlns:pfx4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
        <xsl:for-each select="ShipmentStop/ShipmentStopDetail">
           <LSQNUM>
                <xsl:value-of select="../StopSequence"/>
           </LSQNUM>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ZPOINT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZPOINT xmlns:pfx4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
   <LSQNUM>12412412412414</LSQNUM>
   <LSQNUM>12412412412414</LSQNUM>
   <LSQNUM>123124412412</LSQNUM>
   <LSQNUM>123124412412</LSQNUM>
</ZPOINT>
```

---

### Edit

To add the `Try` values, change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ShipmentStop/ShipmentStopDetail">
   <LSQNUM>
        <xsl:value-of select="../StopSequence"/>
   </LSQNUM>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ShipmentStop/ShipmentStopDetail">
   <LSQNUM>
        <xsl:value-of select="../StopSequence"/>
   </LSQNUM>
    <Change>
        <xsl:value-of select="Try"/>
    </Change>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks I have a small doubt If I want to print  <Try>OTP</Try> what Xpath I need to use <LSQNUM>STOP1</LSQNUM> <CHANGE>OP<CHANGE>

Comment: @SatheeshKumar Sorry, I don't follow. I suggest you edit your question and explain exactly what you want.